# How do you convert binary value strings into ASCII values in Python 3?

Tags: python, binary, ascii, data-conversion

I am trying to convert binary value strings into ASCII values on Python 3. Let's say the letter 'l' in ASCII has a binary value of 01101100. If the '01101100' is represented as a string, how would you convert that string into the ASCII value in Base 10 form (108) into the ASCII character itself?

Comment: What does it matter that it’s ASCII?  You’re just converting binary to decimal.

Comment: Using `int('01101100', 2)`